# About using GridBagLayout in Java

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm learning how to use GridBagLayout. I created two buttons in a JFrame. I tried making it that one of them occupies one collumn (the default), and the other two collumns, thus being twice the size of the first one (I know I can acheive this using setPrefferredSize, but my intention is to learn how to use gridwidth and gridheight).

What's the problem? Thanks

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    Main(){

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500,500);

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JButton b1,b2;
        b1 = new JButton("button 1");
        b2 = new JButton("button 2");

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        panel1.add(b1);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        panel1.add(b2);

        add(panel1);

        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[]args){

        Main m = new Main();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter how many columns the second button's width.

Actually both buttons will be asked for their preferred width and the width will be set to them if it's enough space for them.

If it's less space then min width is used.

If there is extra space it's distributed between controls according to weights proportions.

You can try to set iPadX=100 for the first and iPadx=200 and set proportion iPadX=1 for the first and iPadx=2 for the second.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that all the columns of a GridBagLayout don't have the same width. The widths are computed based on the preferred size of the components they contain. So, you could use 3, 4 or 100 as the gridwidth for the second button, it wouldn't change anything.

You need to use fillx and weightx to change the way the buttons resize.

Answer (score 0):

Try using GridBagConstraint in this way, hope this will help you.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    Main(){

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500,500);

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JButton b1,b2;
        b1 = new JButton("button 1");
        b2 = new JButton("button 2");

       panel1.add(b1, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
       panel1.add(b2, new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 2.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));

        add(panel1);

        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[]args){

        Main m = new Main();

    }

}
```

**EDIT**

Or change in your code Like this below:

```
gbc.gridx = 1;
gbc.gridwidth = 1;
panel1.add(b1, gbc);
gbc.gridx = 2;
gbc.gridwidth = 2;
gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL; //set fill property to HORIZONTAL
gbc.weightx= 2.0;
panel1.add(b2, gbc); //While adding button also add it with gbc
```